# AsyncTask isn't acting correctly

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, classcastexception

I'm having a bit of a breakdown regarding AsyncTask running one moment but not the next. I have simplified the code as much as possible. The try/catch code below launches my async task when called from MainActivity on app start-up. However, when I put this exact same code into a button which is within the same class file, a classCastException error crashes the app. Is there something I am not understanding about Async? Thanks all.

CODE THAT CALLS ASYNC:

```
findViewById(R.id.errorbtn).setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
try {
    new MainActivity.MyTask().execute(this);
}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}});
```

ASYNC TASK:

```
private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, String> {

MainActivity activity;

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {
    activity = (MainActivity)params[0];
    try {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        URL url = new URL("https://www.example.com");
        BufferedReader in;
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        sb.append(inputLine);
        in.close();

        html = sb.toString();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // SOME WORK IS DONE USING HTML VARIABLE & URL DATA...
}

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String str) {

        // RESULT IS LOADED INTO LIST VIEW...
    }
}
```

I THINK THIS IS WHAT YOURE AFTER:

```
09-17 13:09:12.612 17883 17883 I   art com.mycompany.rns                        Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
09-17 13:09:12.612 17883 17883 I   art com.mycompany.rns                        VMHOOK: rlim_cur : 0 pid:17883
09-17 13:09:12.672 17883 17903 I   System com.mycompany.rns                     exec(logcat -v threadtime @ adrt.ADRTLogCatReader.run:42)
09-17 13:09:12.752 17883 17883 D   Atlas com.mycompany.rns                      Validating map...
09-17 13:09:12.782 17883 17907 I   Adreno-EGL com.mycompany.rns                 <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BF.1.1_RB1.05.00.00.002.030_msm8974_refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BF.1.1_RB1.05.00.00.002.030__release_AU ()
09-17 13:09:12.782 17883 17907 I   Adreno-EGL com.mycompany.rns                 OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.03.00
09-17 13:09:12.782 17883 17907 I   Adreno-EGL com.mycompany.rns                 Build Date: 12/11/14 Thu
09-17 13:09:12.782 17883 17907 I   Adreno-EGL com.mycompany.rns                 Local Branch:
09-17 13:09:12.782 17883 17907 I   Adreno-EGL com.mycompany.rns                 Remote Branch: refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BF.1.1_RB1.05.00.00.002.030
09-17 13:09:12.782 17883 17907 I   Adreno-EGL com.mycompany.rns                 Local Patches: NONE
09-17 13:09:12.782 17883 17907 I   Adreno-EGL com.mycompany.rns                 Reconstruct Branch: NOTHING
09-17 13:09:48.952 17883 18854 E   AndroidRuntime com.mycompany.rns             FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
09-17 13:09:48.952 17883 18854 E   AndroidRuntime com.mycompany.rns             Process: com.mycompany.rns, PID: 17883
09-17 13:09:48.952 17883 18854 E   AndroidRuntime com.mycompany.rns             java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
09-17 13:09:48.952 17883 18854 E   AndroidRuntime com.mycompany.rns             at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
09-17 13:09:48.952 17883 18854 E   AndroidRuntime com.mycompany.rns             at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
09-17 13:09:48.952 17883 18854 E   AndroidRuntime com.mycompany.rns             at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
09-17 13:09:48.952 17883 18854 E   AndroidRuntime com.mycompany.rns             at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
09-17 13:09:48.952 17883 18854 E   AndroidRuntime com.mycompany.rns             at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
09-17 13:09:48.952 17883 18854 E   AndroidRuntime com.mycompany.rns             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
09-17 13:09:48.952 17883 18854 E   AndroidRuntime com.mycompany.rns             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
09-17 13:09:48.952 17883 18854 E   AndroidRuntime com.mycompany.rns             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
09-17 13:09:48.952 17883 18854 E   AndroidRuntime com.mycompany.rns             Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mycompany.rns.MainActivity$100000003 cannot be cast to com.mycompany.rns.MainActivity
09-17 13:09:48.952 17883 18854 E   AndroidRuntime com.mycompany.rns             at com.mycompany.rns.MainActivity$MyTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:624)
09-17 13:09:48.952 17883 18854 E   AndroidRuntime com.mycompany.rns             at com.mycompany.rns.MainActivity$MyTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java)
09-17 13:09:48.952 17883 18854 E   AndroidRuntime com.mycompany.rns             at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
09-17 13:09:48.952 17883 18854 E   AndroidRuntime com.mycompany.rns             at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
09-17 13:09:48.952 17883 18854 E   AndroidRuntime com.mycompany.rns             ... 4 more
09-17 13:09:50.632 17883 18854 D   Process com.mycompany.rns                    killProcess, pid=17883
```

Comment: Share your stack trace

Comment: Share your code for launching asynctask from button click.

Comment: Have you tried putting the MyTask class in a separate file?

Comment: rya - I am away from home for awhile and only have access to the free version of AIDE (limited and already used extra pages). It works from within MainActivity.java, as soon as the codes put in the button, which is on that main page, it doesn't work.

Comment: I guess the issue is with context. Please share the button click code.

Comment: Just added a minute ago

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're creating the AsyncTask with a reference to a  View.OnClickListener().

Modify the creation line to this:

```
new MainActivity.MyTask().execute(MainActivity.this);
```

and it should work.

The reason is simple: that line is inside the OnClickListener, and therefore 'this' refers to the Listener, not the activity. You could be more expressive by qualifying the AsyncTask, like so:

```
AsyncTask<MainActivity, Void, String>
```

Comment: This is not really related to your question, but as an FYI, you shouldn't hold strong references to activities inside an AsyncTask. The reason is that if the activity needs to be destroyed before the task finishes, it can't, and so it will leak.

Comment: ahhh, I see whats going on now. Thankyou, it now works beautifully.

Answer (score 0):

You need to structure your code like this (your onPostExecute method is in the wrong place):

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {
    activity = (MainActivity)params[0];
    try {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        URL url = new URL("https://www.example.com");
        BufferedReader in;
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        sb.append(inputLine);
        in.close();

        html = sb.toString();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // SOME WORK IS DONE USING HTML VARIABLE & URL DATA...


}

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String str) {

        // RESULT IS LOADED INTO LIST VIEW...
    }
```

Comment: Sorry that was a typo if you are referring to the doInBackground closing '}'.  That is in my code.